# ANDROID - Displaying a list of IP addresses of phones running same app

Tags: android, client-server

I am developing a multi threaded client-server Android app in which both clients and the server are android phones( the server is not centrally located) and are located in the same network, under the control of one single router.

The server will start the application first. When the clients starts the app, they should get the IP address of the server phone automatically, so that when they click the address, they can be connected to the server.

Right now, I have made a provision that the server phone displays its IP address on the screen when the app starts running. When a client starts the app, it is provided with a text field in which the user can manually type the server's IP address and get connected to it.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how I can get the server's IP address to be displayed on the client phone automatically? Do I need a central database or something like that? I am new to android programming and don't really have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is useful: [Android IP address with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418764/android-ip-address-with-java-net)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about implementing a UPnP solution. See this [Universal Plug and Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) as a starter then check the links at the end for relevant docs/references.

UPnP doesn't require devices to explicitly know the network details of other devices and instead they locate each other using a discovery protocol (SSDP).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to ping local IP range in a loop. Put a small timeout duration. It would be better if you run it in separate threads. If you get ping response, this would mean the server is available.