# Cannot understand how to convert integer to IP in Android and Java

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am building a small application for my android phone. My background in not on computer science
but I am familiar with C/C++ and some development concepts. Now I was trying to display the IP address
of my phone. And according to the Android references I used the `getIpAddress()` method which returns
an Integer.

Then Looking in stackoverflow I saw the solution posted here:
[Android IP address with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418764/android-ip-address-with-java)
which was posted by `Paul Ferguson` and I am copying it here:

```
String ipString = String.format(
"%d.%d.%d.%d",
(ip & 0xff),
(ip >> 8 & 0xff),
(ip >> 16 & 0xff),
(ip >> 24 & 0xff));
```

the `ip` is a variable of type `int` that contains the ip address. Can anyone please explain to me how this works? Note that my java skills are quite introductory.

Thanks to the comments by @Joop Eggen lets say we have an ip address integer of `-926414400` Here is how the code works:

```
IP fileds  <1> . <2> . <3> . <4>

everything is done using the bitwise (and) operation this
means that all operations are made vertically bit by bit

field <1>

ipint    = 11001000 11001000 00001001 11000000
0xff     = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
           ------------------------------------
<1>      = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11000000

which is equal to 192

 Field <2> first we do a shift by 8 bits since
 the >> operator takes precedence over the & operator
 same for fields <3> and <4>

shift by 8 bits  ipint now becomes

ipint    = 00000000 11001000 11001000 00001001
0xff     = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
           ------------------------------------
<2>      = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001

which is equal to  9

For field <3> shift by 16 bits  ipint  becomes

ipint    = 00000000 00000000 11001000 11001000
0xff     = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
           ------------------------------------
<3>      = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000

which is 200


For field <4> shift by 24 bits  ipint  becomes

ipint    = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000
0xff     = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
           ------------------------------------
<4>      = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000

which is 200

So the ip is 192.9.200.200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two standards, [IP v4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) using 4 bytes, and the newer still not too wide spread [IP v6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) with more bytes.

Now in your IP v4 case, the 4 bytes may comprise a Java integer or simply every byte listed.

By the way URLs may use the IP number both as 4 byte values, or as one single integer:

```
http://3232235778/
http://210.43.98.51/
```

*(I did not convert or check the numbers.)*

The code uses a trick, converting the int to long, as java integers are signed; the left-most bit being 1 does not mean a very high number, but negative.

To take out the 4 bytes, every byte 8 bits, they are masked and shifted to the right. Where 0xFF is FF in base 16, 255 in base 10, 0b11111111 or 11111111 in base 2.

There is a bit operation & ("and") which is in fact is multiplication (modulo 2).

```
x  y  x&y  x|y
0  0   0    0
0  1   0    1
1  0   0    1
1  1   1    1
```

Now having some bits `abcdefgh`  and you want to inspect only bits `def` you would do:

```
abcdefgh & 00011100 = 000def00 = def00   (00011100 is called a mask)
(abcdefgh & 00011100) >> 2 = def         (shift right 2)
```

Comment: Ok. Let me tell you what I understand. Java `int` is 32-bit = 4 bytes. Now if those bytes are unsigned(which they are since I have never seen a negative IP in my life) they get values from 0-255. Right? My problem is the bitwise operations. I also do not understand the concept of masking.

Comment: A mask is called a filtering bit pattern see above. And yes, IPs are positive, and if you ever see an IP on a slide with one of the four values above 255, you know it is a not so smart fake.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Now how is this connected to the IP extraction? For the first field he is doing a mask with `0xff = 0b11111111`(according to Google) does the `0b*` means that all the digits from the most significant 1 to the MSB are zero?

Comment: For example I have an integer -926414400 and the 32-bit binary represntation is: `11001000 11001000 00001001 11000000` the `0xff` binary representation is `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111` so with the `&` operation I get `00000000 00000000 00000000 11000000` which is 192. So this is the leftmost ip field.

Comment: Yes that code gives the bytes in order of least significant to most significant bytes (bits). In my memory **that is the wrong order**. That can be easily checked, using the `http://integer/` form.

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer is accepted. Have a look at my original post. I made the complete solution by hand :)

Answer (score 1):

We show you two bit shifting and “0xff” masking examples to convert a decimal number back to IP address. The bit shifting is very hard to explain in words, it’s better review the binary flows below :

```
   //ip = 3232235778
  public String longToIp(long ip) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(15);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        result.insert(0,Long.toString(ip & 0xff));

        if (i < 3) {
            sb.insert(0,'.');
        }

        ip = ip >> 8;
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
```

for more details please check the [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-ip-address-to-decimal-number/)
[Link 2](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1830-converting-ip-addresses-to-and-from-integer-values-with-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: The second link was nice

Comment: Actually should use append() instead of insert() in StringBuilder, Thank's at all.